# Button does not lined properly

Tags: php, html, css, button

[image: Button does not line properly]

As you can see from the picture above , my button will not line properly if they had content inside them.

Please enlighten me why

[ EDIT ]

CSS

```
.button {
    position: relative;

    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 2px solid black;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
 height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

and here is my button

```
<button class="button" id="Btn2"><span>(2)<br><?php 
$id=$_GET['room'];
$day="02";
$month=date("m");
$year=date("Y");
```

( SQL retrieve data )

```
$i=1;
 while ($reserve = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){  echo $i.".  ".$reserve['room_name']." ".$reserve['start_time']." - ".$reserve['end_time']."<br>"; 

$i++;

}
?> </span></button>
```

Comment: Not enough information here.. could you post your html/css code for this so we can take a closer look?

Answer (score 0):

the answer would be css styling ,

which is

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```